# Delete orphan records using Join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete

I got 2 tables as below.  Ideally `Table2.C1` is a foreign key of `Table1.C1` however that foreign key was not setup initially.  We are not able to setup the foreign key now because there are some orphan records exists in Table2 which we want to delete it before applying the alter statement.

Note: I do not want use any sub/nested query

```
Table1
--------
| C1   |
--------
| 1    |
| 2    |
| 3    |
| 4    |
|------|

Table2
--------
| C1   |
--------
| 1    |
| 1    |
| 8    |
| 9    |
| 2    |
|------|
```

I want to delete the records `8` and `9` from Table 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE table2.*
FROM
table2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table2.c1 = table1.c1
WHERE
table1.c1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. how this is different from Pete answer.  Pete answer is also working fine.

Comment: We just have the tables in a different order, so mine is a right join and randy uses a left join

Comment: I just always like to deal with left joins rather than right joins. They functionally do the same thing.

Comment: I normally do, too. It was just to keep the order the same as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE table2.* 
FROM table1 
RIGHT JOIN table2 ON table1.c1=table2.c1
WHERE table1.c1 IS NULL
```